# Does showing term-by-term differentiation of a series via uniform convergence imply that the series defines an infinitely differentiable function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

If I show that

$$\sum 2^{n\alpha} \sin\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)$$

converges uniformly by the M-test, for all x in $R$, then we may differentiate term-by-term everywhere.

Can I conclude from here that the power series must define a $C^{\infty}$ function?

Or must I show that the differentiated series is also uniformly convergent and hence a continuous function, and then use an induction argument?

Answer (score 2):

1) This is not a power series.

2) It is **not** enough to show that the series converges uniformly with each summand being differentiable.

3) It is enough to show that the series of derivatives converges uniformly to show that the limit function is differentiable.

More precisely, if each $f_n : I \to \Bbb{R}$ is $C^1$, if $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges for at least one $x\in I$ and if $\sum_n f_n'$ converges (locally) uniformly, then the series $\sum_n f_n$ converges (locally) uniformly on $I$ and defines a $C^1$ function.

4) You can then in principle use an induction argument to show that the limit is $C^\infty $.

5) In your case, the series is very strange, since the sine term apparently does not depend on $n $ and can thus be pulled out of the series.

Comment: Hi @PhoemueX, regarding your third point, I think you meant to say that it is enough to show that the series of derivatives converges uniformly to show that the limit function, which is the limit of a sequence of partial sums -- a sequence of continuous functions -- is again continuous, by uniform convergence.

Comment: Hence the differentiated series is continuous and defines a $C^1$ function, and from here we make the induction argument, in principle.  I don't think that you can claim the limit function is differentiable - there are usually counterexamples to this claim.  Although I do see what you're saying...once you show the differentiated series converges uniformly, we *will* be differentiating term by term yet again, which implies the differentiability of the series (limit function), but I guess I'm not completely sure about the ordering of the logic here...what do you think?  Thanks, @PhoemueX

Comment: @LebronJames: I am expanded my answer to include your observations. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're very welcome and thank you for your write-up, @PhoemueX :-)