# Does infinite radius of convergence of a power series imply uniform convergence?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, power-series, uniform-convergence

$\sin{x}$ is convergent to its power series for all $x$. I proved this using the Lagrange formula for the remainder showing $R_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Does this imply the power series of $\sin x$ uniformly converges? Because next I'm trying to interchange $\tfrac{d}{dx}$ and summation which is allowed if the sum converges uniformly:

$\dfrac{d}{dx} \sin{x} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} \, \dfrac{x^{2n + 1}}{(2n +1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n} \, \dfrac{d}{dx} \dfrac{x^{2n + 1}}{(2n +1)!}$

Comment: You don't need infinite radius of convergence: if $\sum a_nx^n$ has radius of convergence $R$, then also $\sum na_n x^{n-1}$ has radius of convergence $R$ and if the first power series converges to $f(x)$ for $|x|<R$ then the second converges to $f'(x)$, always for $|x|<R$.

Comment: But, no, it does not converge uniformly. Any finite sum is unbounded.

Comment: Thank you! So proving the radius of convergence of sin x using Lagrange error justifies the interchange of differentiation and summation, right?

Comment: As far as I know, you need the result stated in the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564010/does-showing-term-by-term-differentiation-of-a-series-via-uniform-convergence-im?rq=1) to get what you want (this can be used in proving the result in spectre's comment).